# Firestore get document after creation

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to migrate from Mongo to FireStore.  I am trying to keep my APIs acting consistently.  I am having trouble figuring out how to get the document that was just created(added to a collection) in FireStore.  Here is what I have:

```
loginRouter.route("/create/:email").post((req, res) => {
  const email = req.params.email
  const returning = req.query.returning || false
  if (email) {
    loginsRef.add({
      email,
      loginDate: new Date(),
      returning
    })
      .then(snapshot => {
        loginsRef.get(snapshot.id).then(login => {
          console.log(login.id)
          res.status(200).send(login)
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
          res.status(204)
        })

      })
      .catch(err => {
        serverLogger({ route: "api/logins/create", message: err })
        res.status(500).send("Trouble creating login")
      })
  } else {
    serverLogger({ route: "api/logins/create", message: "No email" })
    res.status(400).send("Please include an email")
  }
})
```

This code will successfully create the login Document in FireStore and return the Document Reference ID. I'd like to then retrieve that full object back from FireStore which I know you cannot do in the create call. Right now the second call is returning an `undefined`.  I was expecting to receive the full Document back on the get call.   I would like for this to come from the Database and not just from memory based on a success FireStore call to have as a proof of concept for more complex endpoints.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what the code is actually doing that's different than what you expect. Note that add() returns a DocumentReference object, not a snapshot. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#add

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the time,  I updated the idea to include that the code right now is returning an undefined. I was expecting to receive the full Document back on the get call I had nested in the .then block of the add call.  Good catch on the variable name, i'll make sure to update that in my code so it is more readable.

Comment: What **exactly** is undefined?  Please be specific.  What do you expect it to be instead?  We can't see the values of any of your variables or data here.

Comment: Good question @DougStevenson, in this case, I'm checking the collection reference ID in my cosonle.log statement.  When I try printing just the collection reference I do get something back, however, I can't seem to pull the Document from the query snapshot

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  I suggest editing the question to show the exact values of each log, and be very clear about what is undefined.  (what you refer to as "the second call" isn't clear).  Walk us through line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to circle back and post the working code I had. Thank you for the help earlier Doug! What I didn't' understand about the FireStore methods was having to do "collection.DOC(ID).get" instead of just "collection.get(ID)".  This was a good learning curve to get through knowing you need to drill down into the next level of the Database to get a singular doc.  The collection would always return all docs.

```
  const email = req.params.email
  const returning = req.query.returning || false
  if (email) {
    loginsRef.add({
      email,
      loginDate: new Date(),
      returning
    })
      .then(docRef => {
        loginsRef.doc(docRef.id).get().then(login => {
          res.status(200).send(login.data())
        }).catch(err => {
          res.status(204)
        })

      })
      .catch(err => {
        serverLogger({ route: "api/logins/create", message: err })
        res.status(500).send("Trouble creating login")
      })
  } else {
    serverLogger({ route: "api/logins/create", message: "No email" })
    res.status(400).send("Please include an email")
  }
})
```